# How can I use igraph to convert edgelist to compressed sparse row format?

Tags: compression, sparse-matrix, igraph, csr, edge-list

I have an undirected edge list of millions of edges.

I'm using [igraph](http://igraph.org/c/) to read my graph data from file. I'm not sure how can I convert edge list into `CSR`(compressed sparse row).

Answer (score 1):

igraph supports two sparse matrix formats. You can get the adjacency matrix in each using

```
igraph_get_adjacency_sparse()
```

and

```
igraph_get_sparsemat()
```

They use the compressed column (CSC) format.

http://igraph.org/c/doc/ch07.html#igraph-SparseMatrices

http://igraph.org/c/doc/ch07.html#igraph-SparseMatrices2